# Stepper motor moves initially but after idle time, clicks and doesn't move for a while

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-mega, stepper

I am using the Accelstepper library to control a stepper motor, according to commands input via Serial. 
It works as expected for the first time when I start Serial Monitor and send command.

When left idle for some seconds (> 10 seconds), the motor makes clicking sounds for the first few commands(without moving) and then it starts working again as expected. The longer I leave it, the more commands it misses.

It gets resolved if I restart Serial Monitor on UNO.

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "AccelStepper.h"

#define STEPPER_X_STEP_PIN 2
#define STEPPER_X_DIR_PIN 3

enum Direction { FORWARD, BACKWORD } direction;

String inputString = "";         // a string to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete

void blockingRunSpeedToPosition();

AccelStepper stepper(AccelStepper::DRIVER, STEPPER_X_STEP_PIN, STEPPER_X_DIR_PIN);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(200.0);
  stepper.setAcceleration(50);
}

void loop()
{
  // print the string when a newline arrives:
  if (stringComplete) {
      // clear the string:
      inputString.trim();
      if(inputString == "x") {
          direction = FORWARD;
          blockingRunSpeedToPosition();
      }
      inputString = "";
      stringComplete = false;
    }
}

void serialEvent() {
    while (Serial.available()) {
        char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
        inputString += inChar;
        if (inChar == '\n') {
          stringComplete = true;
        }
    }
}

void blockingRunSpeedToPosition()
{
    int steps = 400;
    stepper.setCurrentPosition(0);
    stepper.move(steps);
    while (stepper.distanceToGo() != 0) {
           stepper.run();
    }
}
```

I think there is no issue with the code or my Arduino connection since the motor runs fine in the beginning.

I tried the above code on Arduino MEGA, UNO, different motors with different drivers. The problem persists.

I think it is something to do with motor excitation (energized coils).
Please give me some hints and pointer to debug the issue, since I don't know where to look. I am an intermediate programmer and robotics hobbyist.

Here is the [video demo of the issue](https://youtu.be/tjey4Y7v_P4).

I am using:

- Arduino MEGA - ATmega2560
- NEMA 23.
- Rino stepper motor.
- Arduino Pin 2 is Step and 3 is Direction.
- Driver Vcc is connected to 5V pin.
- 48 volt, 5 Amps SMPS.
- Ubuntu 16.
- [Accelstepper library](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/AccelStepper/)

Comment: Reopening the serial monitor probably resets your Arduino, clearing problematic state in the code.  Your program is not very well architected - there's no real point to the expensive String operations you do, or to using the serial event to set a flag you read  in the main loop.  Consider handling everything in the main loop on a character-by-character basis.

Comment: Just checked, restarting serial monitor fixes the problem only on UNO. On mega restarting doesn't effect.

Comment: Will the code keep responding to commands as intended, as long as you don't leave it idle for >= 10 sec?